# Justify a text inside a figure environment

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I insert several figures in my document, but I am unable so far to fully justify the text just below the caption: "BLA BLA BLA"

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
 \caption{NICE TITLE}\label{graph:p}
\begin{flushleft}BLA BLA BLA
\end{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{FIG.png}\\
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

I use `flushleft` because otherwise my text is centered (which is logic since I use the command `\centering`). Without `\centering` and without `flushleft` the text BLABLA is still centered.. Do you have an idea? I use the `\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\caption*` from the `caption` package to add additional text; using `\captionsetup` you can customize the formatting:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{test}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,font=footnotesize}
\caption*{Some additional text}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}% to simulate an actual figure
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your great suggestion. However it is not the caption that I want to be justified, but the text between the caption and my figure :

a caption 
"some justified text" 
my figure

so my caption is above a justified text that is above my figure.. Think of it as the text that would describe a table, but uses a smaller font than for the caption... what do you think?

Comment: What I would like to obtain, Dear Gonzalo, is just having a fully justified text just below the caption. This text can be quite long and this is why I typed it outside the \caption. Therefore you have the title, this justified description and then the figure (or a table) .. :)

Comment: @Fabio Ah, I see now. I've updated my answer. Is is something like that what you want?

Answer (score 6):

What's the problem with the following? Just issue `\centering` when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is for the example
\usepackage{lipsum} % to provide some text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{NICE TITLE}\label{graph:p}

\medskip

\lipsum[2]

\medskip

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{FIG.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\floatfoot` macro. The additional text will be justified by default, and there's no need to add extra commands like `\medskip` or `\captionsetup` within individual floats.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top,footposition=caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{footfont=small}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\floatfoot{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}​
```

[image]