# How can I justify the text under the picture?

Tags: beamer, captions

```
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Kísérletek III.}  
\begin{reference}{3mm}{92.75mm}  
physicsworldarchive.iop.org  
   \end{reference}  
Federico Capasso et al.  
\begin{columns}  
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}  
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,clip]{capasso_setup.jpg}  
\label{fig:capsetup}  
\textcolor{blue}{5. ábra.}   
A kísérlet sematikus rajza.  
\end{column}  
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}  
\includegraphics[width=5cm,clip]{capasso_graph.jpg}  
\label{fig:capgraph}  
\textcolor{blue}{Fig.6.}  
A mikrofabrikált torziós szerkezet (A) és a torziós rúd (B) mikroszkópos felvétele.  
\end{column}  
\end{columns}  
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't this answer help http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86924/15542?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Fig.6. is a caption but I used \textcolor{blue}{Fig.6.}

Comment: You might also find that with a column this narrow, you'll only get satisfactory results with full justification if you can hyphenate the words. Right now, there's not enough room for torziós to fit, and adding additional space on the first line will make it very sparse.

Comment: I tried using "-" but it didn't work.

Comment: I would centre the captions under the pictures rather than trying to justify them. Unless you also want to reduce the fontsize. But, generally, justification does not work well on slides even when you are not dealing with such narrow columns (because even the full width is relatively narrow compared with a normal line of text in a paper, say.)

Comment: Simply adding "-" characters isn't how you do hyphenation. Use `\hyphenation{szer-ke-zet}" in the preamble to indicate where the word szerkezet can be hyphenated. See also [LaTeX Wikibook: Hyphenation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation) for words that aren't in the dictionary, or [LaTeX Wikibook: Internationalization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization) for adding default hyphenation patterns for non-English languages

Comment: You shouldn't mark up the captions by hand. You should configure `\caption` to do what you want, if at all possible.... But justified text is really not going to look good here, even with hyphenation, and will just make things difficult for your audience.

Comment: @cfr I think you should turn your comment into ans answer (ping me if you decide to do so, so I can upvote, if required, to remove this question from the unanswered list).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For what it is worth...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a starting point just to give you the idea. Note the use of semantic markup rather than manual formatting (where possible), and the use of `beamer`'s colour model.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue}
\defbeamertemplate{caption}{mynumbered}{%
  \centering{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}{\insertcaptionname\insertcaptionnumber}} \insertcaption\par}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[mynumbered]
\renewcommand*\figurename{Fig.}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Kísérletek III.}
    Federico Capasso et al.\footnote{physicsworldarchive.iop.org}% replaces reference environment since I've no idea where that is from or what the definition should be!
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[width=4.5cm,clip]{capasso_setup.jpg}
          \caption{%
            {\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}{ábra.}}
            A kísérlet sematikus rajza.\label{fig:capsetup}}
        \end{figure}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[width=5cm,clip]{capasso_graph.jpg}
          \caption{%
            A mikrofabrikált torziós szerkezet (A) és a torziós rúd (B) mikroszkópos felvétele.\label{fig:capgraph}}
        \end{figure}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Semantic slides]